# Prove that $\mathcal{P}(A)\cup \mathcal{P}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I have a presentation this Monday. I thought it was pretty straight forward but my professor wrote "You need to show why $X$ is in $\mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$, not just state that it is." I thought that I had.
Here's what I have:

**Proof**
Suppose $X\in\mathcal{P}(A)\cup\mathcal{P}(B)$.
By definition of union, this means $X\in\mathcal{P}(A)$ or $X\in\mathcal{P}(B)$.
By definition of power sets $X \subseteq A$ or $X \subseteq B$.
**Case 1:** Suppose $X \subseteq A$. Then $X \subseteq A\cup B$, and this means $X\in\mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$.
**Case 2:** Suppose $X \subseteq B$. Then $X \subseteq A\cup B$, and this means $X\in\mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$. 
By case 1 and 2, $X\in\mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$.
Thus $X\in\mathcal{P}(A)\cup \mathcal{P}(B)$ implies $X\in\mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$, and
therefore $\mathcal{P}(A)\cup \mathcal{P}(B)\subseteq \mathcal{P}(A\cup B). \blacksquare$

I am so bad at this. I feel so stupid.

Comment: Don't feel stupid. Your proof is rock solid.

Comment: This is a very nice proof. Good luck on monday.

Comment: I agree that it's a nice proof; you will be fine with this for your presentation.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your proof at all. No wasted words, no confusion. You're hardly bad at this, don't feel stupid, in fact feel pretty good :)

Comment: Omg thanks guys. When he looked at it all he had to say is show why x is in P(AUB) so now I'm all turned around. He doesn't like it. I'm not sure how to fix this because it seems pretty straight forward. I just don't know what he wants.

Comment: Maybe he needs glasses ;/ But seriously, I don't understand his objection, as you *have* proved just that.

Comment: Can you find $A, B$ such that the inclusion is strict? That is, $\mathscr{P}(A) \cup \mathscr{P}(B) \subsetneqq \mathscr{P}(A \cup B)$?

Comment: Perhaps you need to show $X \subseteq A \to X \subseteq A \Cup B$?

Comment: That's what I think too. It's just my book doesn't go into the proof of that, it just says its fact basically. Any hints?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input and taking the time to care. I'm working on a final draft now. Have a great weekend, Alicia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an easier approach (anyway, a different one). We'll use these two general facts:
$$\text{If } X \subseteq Y \text{ then } \mathscr{P}(X) \subseteq \mathscr{P}(Y) \tag{1}.$$

$$\text{If } X \subseteq Z \text{ and } Y \subseteq Z \text{ then } X \cup Y \subseteq Z \tag{2}.$$

These are (very) easy to prove if you haven't already proved them in your course. (*"Proving" them amounts to unpacking the definitions of $\subseteq, \cup$ and $\mathscr{P}(.)$, which reveals that they're trivial. In both cases, the converse is true too.*) Using these truisms, the result follows simply:

Necessarily $A \subseteq A \cup B$, so by (1):
$$\mathscr{P}(A) \subseteq \mathscr{P}(A \cup B) \text{;} \tag{a}
$$
similarly, $B \subseteq A \cup B$, so again by (1):
$$\mathscr{P}(B) \subseteq \mathscr{P}(A \cup B) \text{.} \tag{b}
$$
From (a) and (b), using (2), we conclude:
$$
\mathscr{P}(A) \cup \mathscr{P}(B) \subseteq \mathscr{P}(A \cup B) \text{.}
$$

Comment: In $(2)$, I think you mean $Y\subseteq Z$ after "and"

Comment: @Clayton Yep, just saw that too -- thanks.

Comment: @brianO I wanted to say thank you so much for you help and time. It put a few things in further perspective and I am feeling much more confident now. Much appreciated, best regards, Alicia.

Comment: Oh you're so nice :) Thank you. I'm really glad it helped you understand what's going on with the statement. Best back -- B